# asyncio with multiple processors

Tags: python, async-await, multiprocessing

I notice that `asyncio` doesn't run coroutines on separate processors. For example, if I run the following program with Python 3.6.3, then it uses one of my four cores for 15 seconds, instead of three cores for 5 seconds each.

```
import asyncio

async def myfn(n):
    s = 0
    for x in range(int(n)):
        s += x
    print(s)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(
    [myfn(x) for x in (1e8 + 1, 1e8 + 2, 1e8 + 3)]))
```

Is there a way to use `asyncio`, `async`, or `await` that exploits multiple processors for processor-bound tasks?

Comment: Take a look here: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/multicore_python.html